# Stacked bar chart with different colors and modified hovermode

Tags: r, plotly, stacked-bar-chart

I have the following data table:

```
   dt.data <- structure(list(yyyymm= c("2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", 
"2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", 
"2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-05", 
"2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", 
"2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", 
"2024-05", "2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", 
"2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", 
"2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", 
"2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07"), value = c(0, 
-23760, 720, 720, -13680, 18252, -2160, 3600, 6552, -1420.56, 
20534.4, 2160, 5040, 1980, 0, -24552, 744, 744, -4464, 18860.4, 
-2232, 3720, 10490.4, -1467.91, 15266.88, 2232, 5208, 2046, 0, 
-23760, 720, 720, -720, 18252, -2160, 3600, 10152, -1420.56, 
11174.4, 2160, 5040, 1980, 0, -24552, 744, 744, -744, 18860.4, 
-2232, 3720), testComp = c("Axpo (CH)", "CEZ (CZ)", "EDF Trading (GB)", 
"Energie AG (AT)", "Energie Klagenfurt (AT)", "Engie (FR)", "HSE (SI)", 
"Mercuria (CH)", "OMV Gas M&T (AT)", "RAG (AT)", "RWE (DE)", 
"RWE (GB)", "SEFE (GB)", "WINGAS (DE)", "Axpo (CH)", "CEZ (CZ)", 
"EDF Trading (GB)", "Energie AG (AT)", "Energie Klagenfurt (AT)", 
"Engie (FR)", "HSE (SI)", "Mercuria (CH)", "OMV Gas M&T (AT)", 
"RAG (AT)", "RWE (DE)", "RWE (GB)", "SEFE (GB)", "WINGAS (DE)", 
"Axpo (CH)", "CEZ (CZ)", "EDF Trading (GB)", "Energie AG (AT)", 
"Energie Klagenfurt (AT)", "Engie (FR)", "HSE (SI)", "Mercuria (CH)", 
"OMV Gas M&T (AT)", "RAG (AT)", "RWE (DE)", "RWE (GB)", "SEFE (GB)", 
"WINGAS (DE)", "Axpo (CH)", "CEZ (CZ)", "EDF Trading (GB)", "Energie AG (AT)", 
"Energie Klagenfurt (AT)", "Engie (FR)", "HSE (SI)", "Mercuria (CH)"
)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
))
```

I want to create a stacked bar chart, where the y-axis describes the `value` of each `testComp` and the x-axis describes the column `yyyymm`.

How can I do this?

I want to have a legend for `testComp` and different colors for each of the `testComp`.
Furthermore, it would be nice, when I can customize the hovermode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your dataframe this name

```
dt.data <- data.table(your datahere)
```

##check your dataframe with this code

`dt.data`

##Convert yyyymm column to Date format

```
dt.data$yyyymm <- as.Date(paste0(dt.data$yyyymm, "-01"))
```

##Plot stacked bar chart##

```
 p<-ggplot(dt.data, aes(x = yyyymm, y = value, fill = testComp)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  labs(x = "yyyymm", y = "Value", title = "Stacked Bar Chart") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = rainbow(length(unique(dt.data$testComp)))) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "right") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "testComp")) +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%Y-%m", date_breaks = "1 month") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(legend.key.size = unit(0.7, "cm"))

ggplotly(p, tooltip = c("x", "y", "fill"), hovermode = "x")
```

The result is this with hovermode on:
[image]

**Like it, tick it correct, if its correct for you as shown with hovermode in figure**